# faster way to limit records between range in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-limit, large-data

I have a large number of records in my table , and i want records page wise between limits,but for that we have only one solution

```
WITH data AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
       ,YourColumn
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
    FROM
        YourTable
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    data
WHERE
    RowNum BETWEEN 5 AND 10
```

but for that we require one outer query and this will hit the table twice,like in mysql we can do as follow

```
select * from employee limit 2,4
```

So is there any way we can get the records between range with single hit. bcoz if this is the issue we can never get faster result of that query in MSSQL

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: sql server 2008 R2SP1

Comment: Not sure you have any other choices then. Also not really sure what your problem is with the current syntax honestly, any other way of expressing it would just be sugar anyway.

Comment: This is probably the best you're gonna get in SQL Server 2008. In SQL Server 2012 they added `OFFSET ... ROWS
FETCH NEXT ... ROWS ONLY;`

Comment: first query will bring all records and second query will short list n records.query is taking so much time to execute and with s much users it is blocking my connection pool of sql server

Comment: [Pagination Done the Right Way](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way)

Answer (score 0):

The one you have is the best in SQL Server 2008

Here is another way:

```
--skip first 5 records and display next 5 records
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM data 
WHERE ID
NOT IN(SELECT TOP 5 ID FROM data ORDER BY ID) 
ORDER BY ID
```

If you have `Microsoft SQL Server 2012`:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName 
ORDER BY id 
OFFSET 10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

offset -> # of skipped rows

next -> required # of next rows

Comment: Nice, but which arguments are which?

Answer (score 0):

While the syntax may change between SQL Server Versions it doesn't remove the original performance problem. Even with the SQL Server 2012 syntax if you want a page from the end of the table, the whole table (or index depending on the sort order) has to be scanned, which is very inefficient.

If I assume that the order of the data in the table regarding to your pages does not change often, you can build your own "page index" table. A table that has columns "page number", "start id" and "end id". That way you can get the id range for a given page very fast.

Now of course you have the problem of maintenance for that index table. If the pages are based on your clustered index and that index is an auto-identity, you only need to care for deletes. If you don't have DELETE's, so much the better. If you only delete blocks (through a Stored Procedure) or partitions, you can at these times rebuild the page index. If you have single deletes, you need to write a delete trigger.

Such a helper table can even help you with variable page sizes, should the need arise. Just take some arbitrary page size (like 100) and use the table to additionally limit the query range in your page query. All you need is a static mapping between the row-id and it's position in the table for a number of rows.

Edit: Of course you have to care for inserts also. Best thing there is to keep a counter of how many records are in the last page and generate a new page entry when it exceeds the page limit.